# Confusion about how Pandas DataFrame are created

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am confused about how Pandas dataframe can be created in Python:

- from dictionary
- from list of lists

## Why is this not allowed:

```
import pandas as pd 

dict1 = {'hugo': 1, 'francis': 2}

pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

## Yet, this is allowed:

```
import pandas as pd 

dict2 = {'hugo': [1], 'francis': [2]}

pd.DataFrame(dict2)
```

## Also, how does this work exactly? Why does the dataframe contain a list in its cells?

```
import pandas as pd 

ListofDicts = [{'A' : [1,2,3], 'B' : [4,5,6]}]

pd.DataFrame(ListofDicts)
```

## Whereas, unlike the above, we don't have any lists in any of the cells?

```
import pandas as pd 

ListofDicts = {'A' : [1,2,3], 'B' : [4,5,6]}

pd.DataFrame(ListofDicts)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you first question, this works

```
dict1 = {'hugo': 1, 'francis': 2}
pd.DataFrame(dict1, index = range(0,1,1))
```

With a list, you are already telling how may items are under the columns. If you don't give the input as list, you have tell the dataframe the index at which you want those items to be. Try changing middle 1 to 100, you will get 100 rows with 1 & 2 for 'Hugo' & 'Francis' respectively. You can do `index = range(0,20,2)`, you will see that the index is 0,2,4,6,8...

Similarly, when you pass a dictionary, it is automatically `unpacked` into rows & columns. With the list, you are telling the contents are of each items.
Try this, you will get 20 rows of same data.

```
ListofDicts = [{'A' : [1,2,3], 'B' : [4,5,6]}]
pd.DataFrame(ListofDicts, index = range(0,20,1))
```

Comment: Hi @SH-SF, thank you for answering. Could you please elaborate a little more on **With the list, you are telling the contents are of each items.**. I am still a little confused as to how the pd.DataFrame() function exactly operates when the input is a list, not a dictionary.